# Is there any way in java to limit a package's visibility to only some other package

Tags: java, class, package

I have 2 packages > work and utils, utils I use for stuff that I need to do in classes in work, Classes and methods of work are the ones I want to make available to users who will run this jar, but I don't want them to access the classes and methods of util. If I make them public, users will be able to see all the methods in util, otherwise I wont be able to use them in 'work'. If I make them in a single package there will be too many classes in one package , so if there's a work around please help. I saw similar questions here as well but I didn't find any answers except to document this to client was the best I could find. Or if someone can suggest a better design for this.

Comment: If you don't need your util package to escape beyond the scope of work, then it would make sense for it to be a part of your work package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four access modifiers in Java. The obvious `public` and `private`, then `protected` and `package-private`. Protected is for classes in the same package, and subclasses, while package private (no modifier explicitly declared) is for just the package. So - no you can't do what you ask with just access modifiers.

That leaves you with a couple of choices.

A) As soon as I start to hear "utility classes", it starts to sound like there could be issues in your API design, not implementation. What is wrong in any way with publically accessible classes? It sounds like you are trying to hide some messy or confusing design.

B) Bundle your "utility" functions into abstract base classes. That way concrete instances can inherit the functionality, and make use of `protected`.

C) Have your utility classes communicate via an object that has a package private constructor - and is declared in your "work" package. That way no other package can ever construct the object necessary to use your utilities.

D) Use reflection to call private methods on the utility classes (a right pain).

My choice is by far A). There is absolutely nothing wrong in any way with a nice clean public API to utility classes. There are 10,000's of public classes within the JDK. It sounds like you are focusing a little too much on the how and not the what?

Comment: 'A' seems to be the most fair bet to me by far seeing other options available. Thanks your last sentence really helped.

Answer (score 1):

In Java <9 no, packages cannot be made private within a module. This shortcoming is being addressed in Java 9, with the module system.